# Spring Boot, Hibernate Search properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate-search

How to provide Hibernate Search parameters when using Spring Boot?

```
...
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver

hibernate.search.jmx_enabled=true
hibernate.search.default.directory_provider=filesystem
hibernate.search.generate_statistics=true
hibernate.search.lucene_version=LUCENE_CURRENT
hibernate.search.default.indexBase=/mypath-to-index
```

It does not care what I provide. Default settings always get applied.

I think below code does not have anything to process properties related to Hibernate Search. Can that be the issue?

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaProperties.java

Comment: Where are those properties?

Comment: inside application properties file, at src/main/resources. Other jpa and datasource settings get evaluated fine.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can put them in the application.properties file if you put "spring.jpa.properties." in front of the property names.

Example:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.jmx_enabled=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.directory_provider=filesystem
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.generate_statistics=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.lucene_version=LUCENE_CURRENT
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.search.default.indexBase=/mypath-to-index
```

Spring will take any properties under spring.jpa.properties.* and pass them along (with the prefix stripped) once the EntityManagerFactory is created.

Comment: Great! This is the cleanest solution and it is more in the way of Spring Data JPA ([see here](http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/11/23/spring-boot-and-hibernate-search-integration/)).

Answer (score 3):

Got it working.

Put another property file named "hibernate.properties" inside src/main/resources with below content.

```
hibernate.search.jmx_enabled=true
hibernate.search.default.directory_provider=filesystem
hibernate.search.generate_statistics=true
hibernate.search.lucene_version=LUCENE_CURRENT
hibernate.search.default.indexBase=/mypath-to-index
```