# Spring-boot creating hibernate-search class for initial lucene index

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

In a spring boot (2.0.6) project with hibernate-search-orm (5.11.1) I am trying to create a class to trigger a initial lucene index for data that is already in my database. [(Tutorial Here but doesn't cover how to setup the class)](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-search)

I have tried various annotations on my code, and various attempts at getting this to produce the index, but my current code looks like this ([from SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51827501/hibernate-search-spring-boot-java-lang-illegalstateexception-no-transactiona)):

```
@Service
public class HibernateSearchService {

private final EntityManager entityManager;

@Autowired
public HibernateSearchService(final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    this.entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
}

@PostConstruct
public void initialiseHibernateSearch() {
        System.out.println("About to initalise search");
    try {
        FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
        fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

And my application.properties file has the following config included:

```
hibernate.search.default.directory_provider = filesystem
hibernate.search.default.indexBase = /data/index/default
```

Question: Is the /data/index/default relative to project root or drive root?

The output of the stacktrace does indicate the index is being built:

```
[ntifierloader-1] o.h.s.b.i.SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor  : HSEARCH000027: Going to reindex 4 entities
[  restartedMain] o.h.s.b.i.SimpleIndexingProgressMonitor  : HSEARCH000028: Reindexed 4 entities
```

However there is no trace of /data/index/default on either the root level of the drive or the project root.

I have also tried this code:

```
@Transactional
public class HibernateSearchService {

EntityManager entityManager;

@PostConstruct
public void initialiseHibernateSearch() {
        System.out.println("About to initalise search");
    try {
        FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
        fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

But there is no indication on the stack that the indexing happens and again no trace of the index path being created on the file system.

How can modify my code to correctly trigger this index, and where would I expect to see the path and files created as a result?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474445/spring-boot-hibernate-search-properties you need add spring.jpa.properties. to those properties.